# Apache wicket is it good technology for public sites?

Tags: java, web, wicket

If I want to create site which would be great as PUBLIC SITE, which would be good indexed by Google with human readable paths in http-get requests, fast in runtime and fast and flexible to develop and support etc. Or if i using Java i should use Spring MVC for this purposes ?

Apache wicket seems good for me but I'm not sure about how fast it would be and if it is good solution to create public sites.

Could you help with this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache Wicket is my favorite Java framework. It's component based which actually breaks the very nature of the web. May be useful for intranet sites but if you want to build a public site with probable need of handling high volume then request based framework like Spring MVC would be more suitable.

Comment: Why does being component based break the "very nature" of the web?

Comment: stack-over-flow made using ASP, asp much more like Wicket (but not same of course) than Spring MVC, and it is fast

Comment: there are a lot of high volume installations running wicket. especially in the mobile sector. you can browse the mailing list

Answer (score 4):

Here's a [list](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WICKET/Websites+based+on+Wicket) of public websites based on Wicket, maybe you can use it as a starting point to try to find out how much traffic they handle.
By the way, IMHO Wicket **is** fast and very pleasing to work with :)

Answer (score 2):

For a public website, Wicket can be difficult because of the following reasons:

- Highly depends on sessions: most components are stateful and require
  sessions
- Session should be avoided when building websites that should be
  indexed search engines
- Stateless ajax isn't possible in Wicket

Also see: http://www.jtict.com/blog/wicket-isnt-suited-for-websites/